# Python logging : Automatic log rotation is not happening properly

Tags: python, logging

I have written a `Singleton` module called *logger* in python that uses python's `logging` module. My *App.py* uses *logger* module for handling logs.

1. I ran App.py on 3 Nov 2014 and logger.log (A) was created.
2. I ran App.py on 4 Nov 2014 and logger.log was created. **A** was renamed to logger.log.2014-11-03. So the log rotation happend. That's fine.
3. But when App.py is run by `supervisord` continuously on my production system starting from 5 Nov, I got below results

   (5 Nov) logger.log had logs for 2014-05-01
   (6 Nov) logger.log (size=3.6M+) containing logs for 2014-06-01
   (6 Nov) logger.log.2014-11-05 (size=76M) containing logs for 2014-06-01

**Where did logs for 2014-05-01 go?**

.

My logger.py

```
import logging.config
import sys

class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class Logger(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        print "Logger Init Starts"
        self.configFile = None
        if args:
            self.configFile = args[0]
        else:
            sys.exit("ERROR! Config file not passed to Logger class")
        logging.config.fileConfig(self.configFile)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('Logger')
        self.logger.info('log handler initilizes')
        print "Logger Init Ends"

    def debug(self, msg):
        self.logger.debug(msg)

    def info(self, msg):
        self.logger.info(msg)

    def warn(self, msg):
        self.logger.warn(msg)

    def error(self, msg):
        self.logger.error(msg)

    def critical(self, msg):
        self.logger.critical(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    log = Logger()
```

I use above logger module in my `App.py` module

```
# ... some imports
import logger
class App:

def __init__(self, configFile=None):
    self.configFile = configFile;
    self.log = logger.Logger(self.configFile)
    self.log.info('constructor of App')
# ... more code
```

My config file looks like this

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=file,screen

[formatters]
keys=simple,complex

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=screen,file

[handler_file]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=1
backupCount=0
formatter=complex
level=DEBUG
args=('../../logs/logger.log','midnight',1,0)

[handler_screen]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=simple
level=DEBUG
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simple]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s

[formatter_complex]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s : %(lineno)d - %(message)s
```

Why log rotation is not happening properly? Please help me out here. Thanks.